# In-app purchase response: -1010:Invalid consumption attempt in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to make In-App Purchase in my app. while making testing it, i got error. I have worked by refering the [TrivialDrive](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive).
The payment process done successfully and money is also debited from account but after that problem formed.
[Please see this Image. I have attached the screen short of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLdgp.png)

Anyone please explain me what is the error and how to fix this kind of error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325206/consuming-in-app-purchased-item it may be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. Let me try it first...